# I am trying to sum probes count within subgroup of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, sum

I am biochemistry student working with breast cancer data (Copy number probes). I have the following data frames for primary breast tumors:

```
Patient   Chrom   Start    End       ProbeCount
1         1       51599    62640     8
1         1       88466    16022503  8676
1         2       2785     285255    186
1         2       290880   4178544   2903
...
2         1       51599    4098530   1282
2         1       4101675  46753618  25229
2         2       2785     36178040  25931
2         2       36185342 36192717  21
...
```

I would like to add to add a fifth column where I could add the total of ProbeCounts for each Chrom of each patient:

```
Patient   Chrom   Start    End       ProbeCount   Total
1         1       51599    62640     8            8684
1         1       88466    16022503  8676         8684
1         2       2785     285255    186          3089
1         2       290880   4178544   2903         3089
...
2         1       51599    4098530   1282         26511
2         1       4101675  46753618  25229        26511
2         2       2785     36178040  25931        25952
2         2       36185342 36192717  21           25952
...
```

There must be a simple function for this. Aggregate? I would greatly appreciate if someone could please give me a hint. Thank you!

Comment: This question has been asked in at least 500 different forms, try searching for `dplyr`, or `data.table` and `group by`. I picked a pretty robust answer from a while back, but there are dozens more just like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way with the `dplyr` package would be the following. Your data frame is called `mydf`.

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(mydf, Patient, Chrom) %>%
mutate(whatever = sum(ProbeCount))

#Source: local data frame [8 x 6]
#Groups: Patient, Chrom
#
#  Patient Chrom    Start      End ProbeCount whatever
#1       1     1    51599    62640          8     8684
#2       1     1    88466 16022503       8676     8684
#3       1     2     2785   285255        186     3089
#4       1     2   290880  4178544       2903     3089
#5       2     1    51599  4098530       1282    26511
#6       2     1  4101675 46753618      25229    26511
#7       2     2     2785 36178040      25931    25952
#8       2     2 36185342 36192717         21    25952
```

If your data is large, you may want to use the `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, whatever := sum(ProbeCount), by = list(Patient, Chrom)][]

#   Patient Chrom    Start      End ProbeCount whatever
#1:       1     1    51599    62640          8     8684
#2:       1     1    88466 16022503       8676     8684
#3:       1     2     2785   285255        186     3089
#4:       1     2   290880  4178544       2903     3089
#5:       2     1    51599  4098530       1282    26511
#6:       2     1  4101675 46753618      25229    26511
#7:       2     2     2785 36178040      25931    25952
#8:       2     2 36185342 36192717         21    25952
```